# Joining 3 tables to get only two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three table I need to query table 1,2 and 3 and select C1 from Table 1 and C2 from table 2 and 3 respectively so that it would give result. Is there any way of getting this?
[image]

Comment: what should happen when there are dublicates in C1 of table 2 and C1 of table 3? eg. Table 2 has an entry `A, 1` and table 3 has an entry `A, 4`?

Comment: @Martijn Table 2 and Table 3 has uniquely different values

Comment: Then Mark Bannister has your answer. This constraint is not enforcable in SQL, and it might be a good idea to rethink your data model though.

Comment: @Martijn, the constraint is enforceable but you need to use triggers to do so. I do agree that the datamodel would be better off being redesigned. But sometimes that isn't an option. In that case at least do the triggers so the constraint is enforeced.

Comment: @Martijn  rethinking data model??

Comment: Lik HLGEM says, sometimes you have no choice, but it it could be a good idea to combine Table2 and Table3 into one table, and add an extra column to distinguish them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
select t1.c1, coalesce(t2.c2, t3.c2) c2
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
left join Table3 t3 on t1.c1 = t3.c1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT T1.C1, T2.C2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T1.C1 = T2.C1
UNION ALL
SELECT T1.C1, T3.C2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T1.C1 = T3.C1
```